# qt build output directory being totally ignored

Tags: c++, qt

i've been using qt recently and was organizing some projects into a Subdirs to begin a larger project, and went to manipulate the pro files so as to place my build files where i want them. However, the changes i make to any of them are being ignored. I have a main project that compiles to an executable, and then two other projects that compile to DLL's. I would like for the executables and libraries to end up in the same directory, where the subdirs pro file is located. Here is the pro file for my subdirs that i've tried:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    MainWindow \
    FileLoader

Debug:DESTDIR = $$_PRO_FILE_/debug
Debug:OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
Debug:MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
Debug:RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
Debug:UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.ui

Release:DESTDIR = $$_PRO_FILE_/release
Release:OBJECTS_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.obj
Release:MOC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.moc
Release:RCC_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.rcc
Release:UI_DIR = $${DESTDIR}/.ui
```

After that, i put that same path block in all three of the subprojects pro files, and still all the build files end up in a directory in my Qt Projects directory called "build-Chromatic-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug" (Chromatic is the name of the project). Can someone help me wrangle my pro files to do make this stuff where i want it? Again, i want all the build files for all projects in the directory where the subdirs pro file is.

Comment: The keys are `debug` and `release`, i.e. lower-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of using [_PRO_FILE_](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file) you should use [_PRO_FILE_PWD_](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file-pwd) because the first variable contains the path to the project file in use and the second contains the path to the directory containing the project file in use.
2. In Qt Creator you should [deselect the Shadow build checkbox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-build-settings.html#editing-build-configurations): "*By default, Qt Creator builds projects in a separate directory from the source directory, as shadow builds. This keeps the files generated for each build and run kit separate. If you only build and run with a single kit, you can deselect the Shadow build checkbox.*"