# QMake subdir Template outputs into the build directory instead of the main directory

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to use qmake's `subdirs` template. The problem is that the output directory specified in the sub projects is created in the build directory instead of the directory that is being referenced in the projects. other then that everything works normally. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this.

Dir Structure

```
 build-project_dir/
   -Apps/ --this gets created
   -Other things
 project_dir/
    -main.pro
    -Apps/ -- I want it to use this instead
    -Server/
    ----Server.pro
    ----some logic files
    -Parser/
    ----Parser.pro
    ----Parser files
    -muparser/
      -build/
       ----muparser.pro
       ----main.cpp
```

Main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

# where to find the sub projects - give the folders
Server.subdir = Server
Parser.subdir = Parser
muparser.file = muparser-2.2.5\build\muparser.pro

# what subproject depends on others
Server.depends = Parser
Parser.depends = muparser


SUBDIRS = muparser Parser Server
```

Server.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT       += core sql websockets xml
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Server

CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   += thread


SOURCES += $$files(src/*.cpp, true) $$files(src/*.c, true)
HEADERS += $$files(src/*.h, true)
INCLUDEPATH += src src/things/include

LIBS += -L../lib -lParser

DESTDIR = ../Apps
```

Parser.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Parser

DEFINES += PARSER_LIBRARY

SOURCES += parser.cpp     
HEADERS += parser.h

INCLUDEPATH += ./include 

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/./

LIBS += -L../lib -lmuparser
DESTDIR += ../lib
DLLDESTDIR += ../Apps
```

The reason for this is because there are DLL that are needed there.

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry about that hopefully this is good.

Comment: What is your problem and why is the .pro in the build?

Comment: @eyllanesc The problem is that the DestDir is created in the build directory. instead of simply using the already existing directory. (I am showing this better in the question now). The reason i use .pro in the build is because the muparser.pro is not in the muparser directory. this is a requirement for subdir parameter to work. hence the use of file. this is not a problem however since it does compile, I simply want to to output in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to [Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042400/3738647) I was able to find a solution to the problem

I simply had to change the `DESTDIR` location for my apps to `DESTDIR = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../Apps_Win`